# How to cast an int to any object?

Tags: java, inheritance, interpreter

**I have 2 classes.**

```
    LetLangParser ()
    LetLangExp()
```

**The LetLangExp has subclass ConstExp.**

```
    class ConstExp extends LetLangExp {
        int value;
        public ConstExp(int value){
             this.value=value;
        }
     }
```

**LetLangParser is defined as**

```
    LetLangParser() {
      LetLangExp LcExp;
      LcExp=ParseE();
   }


     static LetLangExp ParseE() {
       ** do some calculation **
       int x= *do some calculation*

      }
```

Here I want to convert x as LcExp. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: `new ConstExp(...);`? It is not at all understandable what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language. You cannot just arbitrarily assign a variable or value of one type (e.g. int) to a variable of a different unrelated type (e.g. LetLangExp). There is no way to do that.

The exception to this rule is that you can assign an int variable to a variable of the Integer wrapper type, because internally Java does autoboxing/unboxing between primitive types and their wrapper types, but this won't work if you assign int to any other type than Integer.

In your case, if you want to pass back the value of x into the value of the variable LcExp, you can pass x using the instance variable in ConstExp subclass. So something like this:

```
LetLangParser() {
      LetLangExp LcExp;
      LcExp=ParseE();
 }


 static LetLangExp ParseE() {
   ** do some calculation **
   int x= *do some calculation*

   ConstExp exp = new ConstExp(x);

   return exp;

 }
```

---

**EDIT:**  As the answer to your follow up question, if you want to print the value returned from the method, you will need to add a getter method to your ConstExp class, to be able to retrieve the value, like this.

```
class ConstExp extends LetLangExp {
    int value;
    public ConstExp(int value){
         this.value=value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Then in order to print the returned value, you need to cast the LcExp variable to its ConstExp sub-type, and retrieve the value using the getter method added above, and then print it, something like:

```
LetLangExp LcExp;
LcExp=ParseE();

//cast LcExp to ConstExp sub-type
ConstExp constExp = (ConstExp) LcExp;

//print the value after retrieving it using the getter method
System.out.println(constExp.getValue());
```

Comment: Just re-read the question and noticed the ConstExp sub-type that I had missed before, so modified the answer to use that class to return the value.

Comment: Cool, good luck!  Also, if you find my answer useful, I would appreciate it if you can mark it as the accepted answer.  :)

Comment: Thanks ! I followed your instructions and when I tried to print LcExp it is showing ConstExp@55f96302, How to print the value of x?

Comment: Yes, if you try to directly print an object, the default toString() implementation in the universal base class, called Object, prints the address of the object in the memory (e.g. instance of ConstExp at the address 55f96302, or written in short as ConstExp@55f96302).

If you want to print the value of the instance variable inside the object, I have edited my main answer above, to show how to do that.